# Reuse a request DTO in other services or decouple it by an identical copy?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Let's say there is a simple REST controller in a Spring Boot application. This controller receives a `CalculationDetails` object which is commonly referred to as a request DTO.

```java
@PostMapping
public CalculationResponse calculateAverage(@RequestBody CalculationDetails details) {
    return calculationService.calculateAverage(details);
}

public record CalculationDetails(@JsonProperty("value_1") BigDecimal bd1,
                                 @JsonProperty("value_2") BigDecimal bd2,
                                 @JsonProperty("sourceList") List<CalculationSource> sources) {}
```

Now, the `CalculationDetails` class is also used in other service methods and mapper classes which use the same data structure, but these services don't represent the same "feature".

I'm asking myself which of these approaches would make more sense:

1. Move the `CalculationDetails` class to a "common" package and reuse it as is in other services.
2. Keep the `CalculationDetails` class specific to this controller/service invocation and create a copy altough the copy would look identically (at least for now).

Approach 2 would surely pay in to decoupling but that would come with the cost of duplication. Approach 1 would allow me to reuse existing code; however, it would create a tighter coupling?

Comment: Which approach most effectively meets your application's specific functional and non-functional requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, go for the first approach. Let's say you add 10 more features which need the same DTO with the same structure. Then you need to duplicate the same code 10 more times. In my eyes it's some sort of technical debt and increases the maintenance cost (in case you change the structure of the DTO).